# Passing variables from vb net to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How do i pass a variable that contain data from sql in vb net to javascript in aspx?

I know there's something like `var y = <%=variable%>` but in my case is y: variable.

The semicolon is obstructing me from passing a variable.

```
series: [{
name: 'Numbers',
colorByPoint: true,
data: [{
    name: 'Server with IP Address', 
    y: 282
}, {
    name: 'Server without IP Address',
    y: 30
```

Comment: This is usually done via a restful service with AJAX.

Comment: P.S You're going to have to provide more code. An object literal alone does not help us to help you...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to get those values to javascript. Here are 2 examples using a variable directly `<%= variable %>` or with a Literal Control

```
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    var withOutIP = '<%= myVariable1 %>';
    series: [{
        name: '<%= myVariable2 %>',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: withIPfromCB,
            y: 282
        }, {
            name: withOutIP,
            y: 30
        }]
    }];
```

Code behind

```
Dim myVariable1 As String = "myVariable1"
Dim myVariable2 As String = "myVariable2"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Literal1.Text = "var withIPfromCB = 'Text';"
End Sub
```